# Solving Nonlinear second order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to know how to solve this nonlinear second order ODE.

This example is based on the option pricing under the CEV model.

$$
\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(x)u''(x)+\mu u'(x)-Cu(x)=-g(x)
$$
where $\mu, C$ are constant, $g(x)=max(x-K,0)/\lambda$.

How to get solutions of above pde???

Comment: Why is it nonlinear?

Comment: This appears to be a linear, non-homogeneous ODE with non-constant coefficients.

Comment: Do we have information about $\sigma(x)$? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a result that the text goes through? or quote a reference to the above? or better still post it on quantstackexchange..

Comment: Yes, $\sigma(x)$ is given by $x^p$ with constant p. In other words, power function of x. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a Bessel option, it is to say when $$ \sigma \left( x \right) ^{2}=x$$ the solution takes the form

[image]

In the case of a hyper-geometric option, it is to say when  $$ \sigma \left( x \right) ^{2}=x(A-x)$$ the solution takes the form

[image]

Comment: Good work, but it is almost pointless to try figure out the function of volatility unless the OP states it. for volatility to be a linear function of stock price may work, but unless this is given in the question it is not great to compute..imo.

Comment: Yes you are very right.  All the best

Comment: It seems were on the right track given that the volatility is a power law. +1